# Is there a way to make Tor more performant and reliable, if necessary at the cost of sacrificing some privacy?

Tags: network-configuration, socks, speed, performance

I have an enterprise use case, where we need to ping a lot of different onion nodes at once, as fast and as reliably as possible.

I have some ideas related to forcing a specific circuit made only of reliable nodes, but I wonder if that even makes sense, as my knowledge of Tor network is severely limited. What are some approaches I could take to create an socks entrypoint for tor traffic that is as reliable as possible and as immune to network issues such as DDoS as possible?